# How can I store a value from a form into mySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I made a form and I want to store the input value of `cat` into my SQL database. Here is my php code:

```
<?php

    $cat = $_POST['cat'];

    if ( !empty($_POST)) {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "UPDATE orders set cat = ?  WHERE id = '$id'";           
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($cat));
            Database::disconnect();

    }


?>
```

And this is my form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">

<div id="modal-content" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

                <h3><?php echo $id ?></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="cat" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"> 
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  </form>
```

Does anybody know why this is not working? No data is stored into the database. The database connection works fine. Thank you

**** Update:

I found my mistake. Here is the result:

```
    <?php

        $cat = $_POST['cat'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];

        if ( !empty($_POST)) {
            $pdo = Database::connect();
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $sql = "UPDATE orders set cat = ?  WHERE id = '$id'";           
                $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $q->execute(array($cat));
                Database::disconnect();

        }


    ?>
```

And the form

```
    <form action="index.php" method="post">

    <div id="modal-content" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <h3><?php echo $id ?></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" name="cat" />
                     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1"/>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer"> 
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: Did print the update statement and run it manually ? enable error reporting

Comment: `WHERE id = '$id'` where are you getting the `$id` from?

Comment: Why is the POST request set to if empty, it should be if isset. So the data will be inserted into the database when the save button is pressed. Also, what is there to update if there is nothing in the database.

Comment: Are you trying to INSERT data?

Comment: I found the mistake! My $id was not defined

Comment: @Jarla Ahh, So I was right x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you had an undefined `$id`.

```
    $cat = $_POST['cat'];

    if ( !empty($_POST)) {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "UPDATE orders set cat = ?  WHERE id = '$id'";           
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($cat));
            Database::disconnect();

    }


?>
```

Instead you should have:

In your HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="check"/>
```

And then in your PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['check'])){
        $cat = $_POST['cat'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];
            $pdo = Database::connect();
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $sql = "UPDATE orders set cat = ?  WHERE id = '$id'";           
                $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $q->execute(array($cat));
                Database::disconnect();

        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `cat` already a column  in your database?

If not you need to make one. Otherwise you cant use update.

Comment: do you use "" around the value of 'cat'?

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing any error checking. Try this:

```
if ( ! $q->execute(array($cat))) {
    echo "ERROR: ".$pdo->errorInfo();
}
```

That will tell you what is wrong.